# Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'

Tags: php, apache, openssl, apple-push-notifications

I sucessfully run the APNS code in my macbook air, but it turns out that I can not run it in my other computer:

I checked that these are the same:
1. .pem file ( to be specific )
2. Program

The computers can not work are:

**Windows 7,XAMPP,OpenSSL supported,No firewall**

And

**EC2 Linux server with 2195 and 2196 opened**

What might be other issues causing that I got this error in my php code?

```
Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'
```

I know there might be cause by not opening SSL, but I checked the phpInfo(), it should be correct.

```
openssl 

OpenSSL support enabled 
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012 
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8x
```

I tried telnet in EC2 server, it gives:

```
telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.36.239...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help, so far I solved the solution.

The problem is that I used the same pem file for both my cert and the root cert.

There is a root cert that is different from my own cert, during connection, both cert is used so I have to get the root cert of apple push notification.

Thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem. Can you share more information of "root cert" and "my cert"? I upload the production and development PEM file of push notification.

Answer (score 2):

In case of **MAC**,
(built-in server was working fine using terminal but not through browser, for me, so i installed MAMP.)

1.Go to---> **/Library/WebServer/Documents**/----copy both **php** and **ckdev.[pem](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)** file here.

2 go to **terminal**-->**$open /private/etc-->go to--->apache2>originals>httpd.config file-->
**"#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so"**, remove "**#**"..(perhaps, you would have to change the permission also..!)

then goto browser and check--> localhost/yourPhpFile.php

In Case of **Windows system**,

1.Install **WAMP**,

2.goto **php.ini** file--->search for this "**;extension=php_openssl.dll**" line and remove semicolon "**;**".

3.click WAMP icon from right-bottom goto **PHP>PHP Extensions>select php_openssl**..

That's it..hope this may help further seekers.

Comment: I have no web server folder on my mac

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are getting an error like this "Unable to find the socket transport “ssl” – did you forget to enable it 
   when you configured PHP?" then follow the next step
2. if php has not got ssl enabled then goto php.ini and change this to  ";extension=php_openssl.dll"
   "extension=php_openssl.dll" (remove the semicolon) and save it and run the program.

Comment: i have updated my description, the ".pem" file is the same, will it cause the problem?

Comment: In the php info, there are:

openssl

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012

Comment: So is there any method? If you want more information, please let me to find~ I really want to solve this.