# iOS APN Php Cannot Connect

Tags: php, ios, swift, push, apn

I followed this youtube tutorial on how to send push notifications: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3YlqWWnI6s

When I run the php file on my webserver however it times out giving me this error.  I have looked at the web and nothing I could find seems to be the problem, can someone suggest where I have gone wrong..

```
[14-Dec-2015 06:13:10 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home2/sptechno/public_html/Wink/sendPush.php on line 18
```

Comment: what OS you are using? linux?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059976/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-gateway-sandbox-push-apple-com2195

Comment: This does not apply, I did not make this error ^

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run `.php` file for Apple push notification.

That time you need to check the TCP/UDP Port number is open on your server other wise notification not pass to apple server.

> General Provider Requirements
>
> As a provider you communicate with Apple Push Notification service
> over a binary interface. This interface is a high-speed, high-capacity
> interface for providers; it uses a streaming TCP socket design in
> conjunction with binary content. The binary interface is asynchronous.
>
> The binary interface of the production environment is available
> through gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195; the binary interface of the
> development environment is available through
> gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195.

[Apple official document for that.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

**EDITED**

Check for your server is connected to APNS.

> HOSTGATOR:~ Home$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
>
> Trying 17.149.34.143...
>
> Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Its an outbound request though, why would I have to open the port on my server?

Comment: You must   TCP port 2195 open for sending the APNS.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG41